# Hessian of composite function depending on a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, hessian-matrix

Consider the following function depending on a another function, which depends on a parameter $\theta$:

$$ E(F(\theta))$$

The hessian is given by: $$H= \partial^2_{\theta} E = \partial_{\theta} F^T \partial^2_{F} \partial_{\theta} F + \partial_{F} E \ \partial^2_{\theta} F  $$

Where does the second term came from?

Comment: Your notation ts confusing. What is $g$? Is $\theta$ a real number?Please specify the domain and co-domain of $E$ and $F$.

Comment: Sorry g was a mistake. $\theta$ should be a vector of parameters which F depend on. I only wanted to understand the idea why the second term is showing up